# I want to find a name after the first 9 characters

Tags: c#

(not an actual person)

```
55705541;Henrik;Winther;50;7080;Børkop;hew@larsen.dk;0
60015956;Emilie;Beitzel;63;1610;København V;emb@senior.dk;1
44243159;Emilie;Kristensen;14;1125;København K;emk@jubiimail.dk;2
```

I want it so i can use a readline and find the index i need.

I want to use `array.find` to locate `"Henrik;Winther"` but i cant seem to skip the first 9 characters.

After finding the index, i want to use `.Replace(";", "  ");` and display it with an write line.

Input: Henrik winther

Output:

```
55705541 Henrik Winther 50 7080 Børkop hew@larsen.dk
```

Comment: You don't have an array (unless you consider it to be an array of characters, but then you would be searching for individual characters). Perhaps you want `myString.IndexOf` or `myString.Contains` where `myString` is your string value?

Comment: You can use `Skip(9)`, literally. Is the name always going to be in that same position?

Comment: Looks like a CSV derivate using ";" as delimiter. So why not `string[] colums = inputstring.Split(';'); Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", columns[1], columns[2]));` ?

Comment: ^^ See https://dotnetfiddle.net/PVRiCT

Comment: It is not not clear what you want. Why the `0` at the end is not there in the output you have shown? How/why does an input of "Henrik winther" return such an output? I mean what's the logic here?

Comment: I guess i havent given enough information. I have this array of profiles and i need to make a search engine for a user. When the user inputs a name it needs to find the profile and display it, and i use ´.Replace´ to remove the ;

Comment: Thought exactly that. Just wanted you to confirm this.

Comment: I used this  string value = Array.Find(databaseNavne, element => element.StartsWith(søgenavn, StringComparison.Ordinal)); But it only takes the first characters.

Comment: What is `databaseNavne`?

Comment: Thats the string[] index, and "søgenavn" is the readline

Comment: @Abdey Take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: @Fildor That's what I thought too initially, but looks like the OP wanted something else entirely ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: "Asking questions well", a widely and wildly neglected skill. @Sнаđошƒаӽ :D

Comment: Thanks for the help, it runs perfectly. To be fair, im really new to programming, so wording questions will be a skill i need to improve upon.

Answer (score 2):

(The question has been edited heavily)

Here are the steps you can follow:

1. Make the input `;` separated, since the strings in your database (I presume) are that way.

   ```
   søgenavn = String.Join(";", søgenavn.Split());
   ```
2. Search for the input in the array, ignoring the case, of course

   ```
   var line = databaseNavne.Where(x => x.IndexOf(søgenavn, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0).FirstOrDefault();
   ```
3. If line is `null`, no such line exists in the `databaseNavne`. Otherwise the line would be whatever's in the `databaseNavne`:

   ```
   55705541;Henrik;Winther;50;7080;Børkop;hew@larsen.dk;0
   ```
4. You can split it with `;`, chop it, cook it, boil it and do all sorts of stuffs. To get the space separated form like you showed in the question, do this:

   ```
   line = String.Join(" ", line.Split(';'))
   // 55705541 Henrik Winther 50 7080 Børkop hew@larsen.dk 0
   ```

The output you have shown does no have the `0` at the end though. Dunno who ate that away.

---

**Old answer:**

Considering the name is always going to be in the same position, you can use this to extract the name:

```
string inputStr = "55705541;Henrik;Winther;50;7080;Børkop;hew@larsen.dk;0"
string name = String.Join(" ", inputStr.Split(';').Skip(1).Take(2))
```

The code speaks for itself.

- `Split` by `;`. This returns an array of strings
- `Skip` the first string, which in your example is 55705541
- Then `Take` 2, in your example "Henrik" and "Winther". This also returns an *array* of strings (I said array only to keep things simple for the OP, I know it doesn't return an array)
- `Join` the strings using a single space.

Comment: I forgot to mention its an index, so i have to find the users input in the index first.